# When is the condition of this for loop will becomes false?

Tags: c++, logic

I'm working on my C++ practice question to prepare for my upcoming test and I'm struggling with a for loop condition that I have never seen before.

```
        for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++)
```

The string `s` that has been sent from the main is `"Two roofs to fix"`

The question is when is the for loop's condition will become false?

Comment: Hint: the string `"Two roofs to fix"` has a null-terminator at the end of the string. What do you think a null-terminator evaluates to in the second expression of the `for` loop?

Comment: So what are you saying is after the string it should stop because it can't go further than that correct?

Comment: @Ali: The null terminator `\0` at the end of your string has the value of zero, which converts to false.

Comment: that make more sense for me Thanks @Jesse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop condition becomes false, when the string's terminating zero `'\0'` is hit. (`if (0)` evaluates to false)

Please note: this form of test is a possible error waiting to happen if the string isn't null terminated.

Comment: -1: If he knew that strings ended in '\0', I'm fairly sure he wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: Looking forward to seeing your more 'complete' answer to justify your downvote, otherwise I'd appreciate you removing the downvote.

Comment: According to @NicolBolas logic, everyone who answers a question on SO should be getting downvotes since the OP doesn't know the answer to their own question!

Comment: @Marlon: It should be noted that the answer I was responding to has changed (and changes aren't tracked until after the 5 minute grace period) into something more complete. All he mentioned originally was that the loop would continue until `\0` was hit, not explaining that strings end in those implicitly.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: the answer I have posted has not changed in any substantial way. If I choose to post a partial answer and then flesh it out, that's fine. Many people do this (even Jon Skeet) Your downvote is completely unjustified. But this is the internet....

Comment: Yes, another reader who knows _beforehand_ that string literals are null-terminated, but wouldn't have benefited from this answer at all if he didn't.

Comment: @ildjarn : the poster accepted the question: he seemed pretty happy with it, along with the 7 upvoters.

Comment: So you're saying I _shouldn't_ have told you why I downvoted when you asked? Make up your mind.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify @MitchWheat's answer, if an expression used as a condition specifies only a value, like `if (x)`, then it's essentially equivalent to `if (x != 0)`. If the value is a pointer type, then  it's equivalent to `if (x != NULL)` instead (though that's not really an "instead", since NULL == 0).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "Two roofs to fix";
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i]; i++);
    cout<<"i = "<<i<<endl;
}
```

I test the problem with the above code. It returns an error "string subscript out of range". So if the length of string s is Len, s[Len] is illegal.
In your code, s is not a pointer char*, but a string. So it is unappropriate to code like this.

Comment: He said string, but he wasn't clear about `std::string` or `char*`. Since he didn't mention any errors, I'd assume it's `char* s;`